# Is there a better way to draw a contour and clear each frame?

Tags: python, opencv

I am working on building an interactive rectangle for various OpenCV methods. The big box will be the final contour I feed into the OpenCV methods, and the small boxes and circle are resizing tools. This all works fine except for when I have a large image(I grabbed an iphone image roughly 4000 x 4000). With the larger images, the manipulating of the rectangle is no longer fluid.

I understand that it also may be in the methodology that I've implemented my translation/rotation logic, but I'd like to first check if there is a better way to draw/redraw each frame:

```
    def redraw(self):
       self.image = self.image_display.copy()
       self.plot(self.image, color=(0, 0, 255),thickness=self.line_thickness)
       self.updateimg = True
```

Upon initialization, I make a copy of the image I'm working on and once I redraw, I copy that said fresh image from my copy and then redraw the contours.

Is there a better way to go about this? I was looking into bitwise_and and just plain adding, but there were masks I had to generate first and it seemed as if it would be much more of a hassle.

[image: interactive ROI rectangle]

Comment: you will need GPU-accelerated drawing (and I mean for the lines/boxes), i.e. OpenGL/Vulkan/D3D/D2D/... doing this on a CPU will be "slow" because you're used to programs that use graphics acceleration.

Comment: Understood, i'm not an expert so I was figuring I was missing out on some sort of image addition/bitwise and operation that would be more efficient. Why i'm asking this is because Cognex's InSight editor is way more responsive and i've used that on basic desktops deployed in the field which do not have a dGPU.

Comment: if you remember windows 95, its selection rectangle and the outlines of dragged windows relied on xor or some other thing... once to make a rectangle... once to undo it, once more to draw it elsewhere. I doubt opencv has a line drawing mode that does this. could be added besides LINE_AA maybe... or DIY (straight lines are trivial). but if you were thinking of mixing whole images per pixel, it's still going to take a little time. you could try it. OpenCV and numpy each have ways to achieve it.

Comment: Cognex probably doesn't draw the whole picture every time, or they keep downsampled versions around. that's a typical "cheat". downscale the background, then draw on it in screen space. that's reasonably fast. or, in the case of zoom, draw the region that's visible. they probably use some graphics acceleration from the operating system or GUI library... anyway, you should show your code and make it reproducible, and quantify the time/performance, so people can investigate. as it is, you will not get anything better than guessing.